# C syslog Wrapper

Tags: c, syslog, busybox

I am trying to use `syslog` and a custom `syslog.conf` to create a logger for multiple modules. I have created a logging struct that allows a module to create a logger with custom settings

```
struct module_logger {
    char* logger_name;
    int32_t logger_options;
    int32_t logger_facility_code;
    int32_t log_level;
    int32_t log_mask;
};
```

When a module initialized the logger they struct values must be passed in. I have two functions `logger_log` and `logger_log_at_level`

```
void logger_log(struct module_logger* logger, char* message) {
    (void)setlogmask(logger->log_mask);
    openlog(logger->logger_name, logger->logger_options, logger->logger_facility_code);
    syslog(logger->log_level, "%s", message);
    closelog();
}

void logger_log_at_level(struct module_logger* logger, char* message, int32_t log_level) {
    (void)setlogmask(log_level);
    openlog(logger->logger_name, logger->logger_options, logger->logger_facility_code);
    syslog(log_level, "%s", message);
    closelog();
}
```

My syslog.config is very simple, take each log and put them into their own file

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf     Configuration file for busybox's syslogd utility

user.emerg  /var/log/emerg
user.alert  /var/log/alert
user.crit   /var/log/crit
user.err    /var/log/err
user.warning    /var/log/warning
user.notice     /var/log/notice
user.info   /var/log/info
user.debug  /var/log/debug
```

I wrote the following test code

```
struct module_logger logger_emerg;
struct module_logger logger_alert;
struct module_logger logger_crit;
struct module_logger logger_err;
struct module_logger logger_warning;
struct module_logger logger_notice;
struct module_logger logger_info;
struct module_logger logger_debug;

int main(void) {

    logger_init(&logger_emerg, "logger emerg", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_EMERG, LOG_EMERG);
    logger_init(&logger_alert, "logger alert", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_ALERT, LOG_ALERT);
    logger_init(&logger_crit, "logger crit", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_CRIT, LOG_CRIT);
    logger_init(&logger_err, "logger err", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_ERR, LOG_ERR);
    logger_init(&logger_warning, "logger warning", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_WARNING, LOG_WARNING);
    logger_init(&logger_notice, "logger notice", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_NOTICE, LOG_NOTICE);
    logger_init(&logger_info, "logger info", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_INFO, LOG_INFO);
    logger_init(&logger_debug, "logger debug", LOGGER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, LOG_USER, LOG_DEBUG, LOG_DEBUG);

    while(1) {
        logger_log(&logger_emerg, "emerg message");
        logger_log(&logger_alert, "alert message");
        logger_log(&logger_crit, "crit message");
        logger_log(&logger_err, "err message");
        logger_log(&logger_warning, "warning message");
        logger_log(&logger_notice, "notice message");
        logger_log(&logger_info, "info message");
        logger_log(&logger_debug, "debug message");

        logger_log_at_level(&logger_debug, "debug at emerg", LOG_EMERG);
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

When I view my `/var/log` folder there are 8 log files, one for each level. But there is an issue. All the files have the same contents. They only contain the messages from

```
Mar 24 10:25:27 imx6ull14x14evk user.emerg logger emerg[164]: emerg message
Mar 24 10:25:27 imx6ull14x14evk user.emerg logger debug[164]: debug at emerg
```

My other messages are seemingly lost. I believe the error is in my logging functions but I am not sure what I am missing.

Edit: Logger init as requested

```
void logger_init(struct module_logger* logger, char* name, int32_t options, int32_t facility_code, int32_t log_level, int32_t log_mask) {
    logger->logger_name = name;
    logger->logger_options = options;
    logger->logger_facility_code = facility_code;
    logger->log_level = log_level;
    logger->log_mask = log_mask;
}
```

Edit 2: The error is definitely in my log function. Printing out the last log mask I see

```
last level 255
logger emerg[278]: emerg message
last level 255
last level 1
last level 2
last level 3
last level 4
last level 5
last level 6
last level 7
```

Edit 3: If I change the log mask to `setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(logger->log_mask));` Then I get better results. In the `emerg` log only emergency logs appear. In my debug log I get all messages. I want all 8 files to only get their respective messages.

Comment: Can you show your `logger_init`?

Comment: I have add it under the Edit header

Comment: I haven't used the BSD-based syslog facility, but according to the `syslog.conf` manual, *...all messages of the specified priority and higher are logged according to the given action*. So it's not clear to me, at the moment, that you can completely separate them in the manner you're trying to do unless I'm reading that wrong. I would suggest do some tests with raw syslog operations, without your logger implementation, first and establish that the config does what you want. Then move to your logger implementation.

Comment: @KamilCuk I do that incase two module loggers are using different settings.

Comment: @lurker I do believe you are correct. A syslog conf line for debug will place everything into that debug log.